# spacing of slash in mathmode

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I want to get `\setminus` to use the spacing of an ordinary forward slash. I've tried things like `\mathbin`, `\mathop`, and `\mathrel`, but they don't give me what I want:

```latex
\begin{align}
A &/ x & A &\setminus x \\
A &\mathop{/} x & A &\mathop{\setminus} x \\
A &\mathbin{/} x & A &\mathbin{\setminus} x \\
A &\mathrel{/} x & A &\mathrel{\setminus} x \\
\end{align}
```

[image]

Is the slash not treated as a binary operator of some kind? How can  I get another symbol to get treated like slash, spacewise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to use `\mathord{\setminus}` or, more simply, `{\setminus}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
$A / x$  
$A {\setminus} x $
$A \mathord{\setminus} x $
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want `\backslash`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$A/x$ $A\backslash x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The two symbols are mirror images of one another and the apparent asymmetry in the picture is just an optical effect due to the shapes of the surrounding characters.